# RxJS 6 Pause or buffer observable when the page is not active

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs, rxjs6

So I have a stream of, let's say letters, and I need all letters in the right order to put them together into a word. Everything works fine until the user changes tab, minimize browser or switches application - behavior is almost the same as if I was using `setTimeout()` - messed up the order, lost items, etc. I tried to achieve my goal by using `bufferWhen()`, `bufferToggle()`, `takeUntil()`, `publish()` and `connect()` but nothing succeeded. I considered to use `delayWhen` as well, but it's deprecated and probably not suitable as it stops the stream immediately. Which functions should I use and how? Here's my code:

```js
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  private visibilityChange$ = fromEvent(document, 'visibilitychange').pipe(startWith('visible'), shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: 1 }));
  private show$ = this.visibilityChange$.pipe(filter(() => document.visibilityState === 'visible'));
  private hide$ = this.visibilityChange$.pipe(filter(() => document.visibilityState === 'hidden'));

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    const lettersStream$ = zip( // add delay for each letter
            from(['w', 'o', 'r', 'd']),
            interval(1000))
           // pause when hide$ fires, resume when show$
          .pipe(map(([letter, delayTime]) => letter))
          .subscribe(console.log);
  }
}
```

I made a demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ohkzkm?file=index.ts) - all I want is to see (stop writing when the tab is inactive) how the phrase is written on the screen.

Comment: Something like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m3fvhr

Comment: Mmm, no. The letters are consecutive values emitted by an observable, you made observable `of` instead `from` them. I get "w", then 1 second later next letter and need to keep the order besides interruptions caused by changing browser tab.

Comment: I could not see how you are using `show$` and `hide$` observables in your `letterStream$`. I could only see a comment which mentioned about them. Am I missing something?

Comment: what is the actual source here? is it a websocket of some kind that's disconnecting when the tabs change? or is it a document event or something? I'm confused what is causing the problem here or why you need to pause this stream when the visibility changes

Comment: The source is like in the example, Observable emitting values, it's not disconnecting, it's just the browser giving priority to visible tabs, so e.g. "d" item can be handled before "r".

Comment: @user2216584, yup, they are not used in the example, just intended to be - and the question is "how?"

Comment: using from([]) as a source is confusing because it doesn't behave like a traditional source, as it emits it's entire sequence on every subscription... I've posted an answer outlining how to pause an observable generally but what you're after here is a little confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since I have done similar pause/unpause thing in my [RxJS Snake Game](https://github.com/gogakoreli/angular-7-rxjs-snake-game), I will help you with your example.

Idea is to have an `interval(1000)` as a source of truth, which means that everything will be based on it. So our goal becomes to make this interval pausable, based on the fact that we need to stop emitting events on visibility hide and continue on visibility show. Finally to make things easier, we can just stop listening to the source interval on visibility hide and start listening again when visibility show arrives. Let's now go to the exact implementation:

You can play with the modified StackBlitz demo code as well at [RxJS Pause Observable](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-pause-observable).

```
import { of, interval, fromEvent, timer, from, zip, never } from 'rxjs';
import { delayWhen, tap, withLatestFrom, concatMap, take, startWith, distinctUntilChanged, switchMap, shareReplay, filter, map, finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

console.log('-------------------------------------- STARTING ----------------------------')

class MyComponent {
  private visibilityChange$ = fromEvent(document, 'visibilitychange')
    .pipe(
      map(x => document.visibilityState),
      startWith('visible'),
      shareReplay(1)
    );

  private isVisible$ = this.visibilityChange$.pipe(
    map(x => x === 'visible'),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
  );

  constructor() {
    const intervalTime = 1000;
    const source$ = from('word or two'.split(''));
    /** should remove these .pipe(
        concatMap(ch => interval(intervalTime).pipe(map(_ => ch), take(1)))
      );*/

    const pausableInterval$ = this.isVisible$.pipe(
      switchMap(visible => visible ? interval(intervalTime) : never()),
    )

    const lettersStream$ = zip(pausableInterval$, source$).pipe(
      map(([tick, letter]) => letter),
    ).subscribe(letter => {
      this.writeLetter(letter);
    });
  }

  private writeLetter(letter: string) {
    if (letter === ' ') letter = '\u00A0'; // fix for spaces
    document.body.innerText += letter;
  }
}

const component = new MyComponent();
```

This is exact code from StackBlitz, I copied here to explain better for you.

Now lets break down interesting parts for you:

1. Have a look at `visibilityChange$` and `isVisible$`. They are modified a little, so that first one emits string value `'visible'` or `'hidden'` based on `document.visibilityState`. Second one emits true when `document.visibilityState` equals `'visible'`.
2. Have a look at `source$`. It will emit a letter and then wait 1 second with the help of `concatMap` and `interval` with `take(1)` and do this process until there is no character left in the text.
3. Have a look `pausableInterval$`. Based on `this.isVisible$` which will change according to the `document.visibilityState`, our `pausableInterval$` will be emiting item per second or will not emit anything at all due to `never()`.
4. Finally have a look at `lettersStream$`. With the help of `zip()`, we will zip `pausableInterval$` and `source$`, so we will get one letter from source and one tick from pausable interval. If `pausableInterval$` stops emitting due to visibilitychange, zip will wait as well, since it needs both Observables to emit together to send event to the subscribe.

Answer (score 2):

a little confused on the use case, but this may solve it:

first instead do this:

```
private isVisible$ = this.visibilityChange$.pipe(
                       filter(() => document.visibilityState === 'visible'), 
                       distinctUntilChanged()); // just a safety operator
```

then do this:

```
const lettersStream$ = this.isVisible$.pipe(
        switchMap((isVisible) => (isVisible)
          ? zip( // add delay for each letter
              from(['w', 'o', 'r', 'd']),
              interval(1000))
            .pipe(map(([letter, delayTime]) => letter))
          : NEVER
        )
      ).subscribe(console.log);
```

just switchMap everytime the visibility changes, subscribe to the source if visible, do nothing if not.

with this contrived example, the behavior will be a little wonky because from() will always emit the same sequence but with a real non static source, it should work as intended.

Comment: I'm creating a demo and used your code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-nsyvne?file=index.ts
`word or twowwwwww...` was printed and it's continuing...

Comment: This is due to the nature of `from` as a source. everytime a subscription occurs, it reemits it's entire stream.  but the pause is functioning as expected. it cancels subscription and resubscribes on every visibility change.

Comment: Okay, so how to do it with a `from`?

Comment: you can't. you'd need to write some kind of source that can be paused, but there is no way using from as a source to stop and then resume emissions mid stream.  from generally isn't very realistic for how osbervables behave in the wild and is mostly for demos and has few obscure use cases in practice. it's still very unclear what you're actually after here.